# Test secured WebAPI with HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to test my Web API

```
  [Test]
    public void PolicyController_GetFirstPage_Successful()
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost/api/policies/~/~/0"))
        {
            using (var response = Client.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None).Result)
            {
              //blah blah
            }
        }
    }
```

But my controller's action has `[Authorize]` attribute, so I am getting unauthorized error.

How can I handle this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just set Thread.CurrentPrincipal and it now works fine.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get access token. And then you can send GET request with access token inside headers. You can read more about this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx

Here is working console app example. It's quite hardcoded but works fine with my test app, so I hope it will be useful for you.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("App started");

        var tokenUrl = "http://localhost:29825/token";
        var userName = "stack";
        var userPassword = "password";
        var request = string.Format("grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userName), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userPassword));
        var token = HttpPost(tokenUrl, request);
        var url = "http://localhost:29825/api/clients";
        var clients =  HttpGet(url, token.access_token);

        foreach (var client in clients)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(client.Name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    private static AccessToken HttpPost(string tokenUrl, string requestDetails)
    {
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(tokenUrl);
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestDetails);
        webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream outputStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AccessToken));

            AccessToken token = (AccessToken)serializer.ReadObject(webResponse.GetResponseStream());

            return token;
        }
    }

    private static List<Client> HttpGet(string url, string token)
    {
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

        using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Client>));

            List<Client> clients = (List<Client>)serializer.ReadObject(webResponse.GetResponseStream());

            return clients;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class AccessToken
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string access_token { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string token_type { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string expires_in { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string userName { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Client
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant to what I am asking. I am not using azure and not using Translator Api.

Comment: Yes it's relevant. I added example to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, you must have misunderstood me. Or I was unclear, I am doing unit tests of my web api controllers.